# How to get yaw and pitch value from mouse event

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am displaying a panorama image in my html web application in canvas. If user click on image at any screen position I have the requirement to get/calculate the yaw and pitch value for that mouse clicked position.

Is there a way to get the yaw and pitch value from mouse click position on panorama image? Please help me with sample code or logic I am new to this threejs and panorama world and any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please upload the code somewhere so that we can check it. It's best to mention what you have tried so far. On topic: have you tried https://github.com/google/marzipano ? What plugins/libraries are you using?